# Checking SFTP and SQL server permissions using Scala

Tags: sql, scala, permissions, sftp, credentials

I'm working with the Play framework, using Scala(with slick) I'd like to be able to check the permission for a user for the connection types:

1) SFTP connection 
2) SQL connection (sqlserver, postgres, redshift, mysql)

and list out what types of access they have with their credentials.  I know this question might seem broad and may require specifics on what level of granularity I want, but was hoping someone could advise on where to get started as I'm still very new to programming.

Any guidance would be really appreciated!

Comment: Guess it is Redshift :)

Comment: @Ven - thank you for that!

Comment: How about firewall restrictions, and account type SQL server is running under